# Nonstop color changing on hover

Tags: html, css

I need to change the color of the elements automatically to be infinitely running, with the following code achieving the effect I want, but only when the mouse passes through the element (div). How can I do that so it's always changing the color?

Thanks and Regards.

```
.box{
background-color: #900;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
padding: 1em;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
transition:background-color 3s linear;
-webkit-transition:background-color 3s linear;
-o-transition: background-color 3s linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 3s linear;
-ms-transition: background-color 3s linear;

}

.box:hover{
background-color: #090;


}
```

Comment: When the mouse enters the element's div you want the transition to run infintely  changing between colors without stopping? Kindly clarify your request....

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [CSS keyframes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/).

```css
@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    background-color: #900;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #090;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #900;
  }
}
.box {
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  background-color: #900;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Sure, was this the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect by using css animation (Key frames) . read it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)

```css
.box {
  background-color: #900;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background-color 3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 3s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 3s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 3s linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 3s linear;
}
@keyframes hoverme {
  0% {
    background-color: #900;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #900;
  }
}
.box:hover {
  animation: hoverme 3s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Hover me :)
</div>
```